# Generate XML Request Payload with Template in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, templates, faraday

I'm working on a rails app that integrates with a 3rd party on the backend. To give a quick overview, a user will create an order in our web interface and that will persist a delayed job. So, the job runs outside of a web context and will send a request to this 3rd party. The 3rd party expects a POST with an XML payload in the request body.

I'm currently using Faraday to do the request. I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class FooRequest
  def response
    connection.post("/foo", xml)
  end

  private

  def xml
    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
    xml.root do
      xml.foo "something something"
    end

    xml.target!
  end      

  def connection
    @connection ||= Faraday.new(url: "http://example.org")
  end
end
```

The XML is actually bigger and more complex than that and so I don't want to build the xml in this class. I think having some sort of template is best. I'd either like to use Builder in a `xml.builder` file or just have raw XML in a erb file. Not sure which is best and how best to render a template in this context. I know that rails recently added the ability to render views outside of a controller context (https://medium.com/evil-martians/new-feature-in-rails-5-render-views-outside-of-actions-2fc1181e86a8#.s344qg5ue) but I feel like that feature wasn't built for this use case. I also know that there are other templating languages like Liquid and maybe that's a better fit.

Has anyone done this sort of thing in the past? Is there something I'm missing?
Also, if I do create a template file, should I put it in `/app/views`? It's not a view that my webapp would render, maybe I should have a `/app/templates` dir?

PS: Rails's `to_xml` method is not robust enough for what I want (I need tag attributes and I don't want to represent a deep complex XML tree with a ruby hash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a similar thing, the easiest way I found was to implement whatever XML classes I needed into a separated gem (you don't really have to do this you can just add the classes somewhere in the models folder, it made sense for my use case).

I used [ROXML](https://github.com/Empact/roxml) for this; after that you can simple call `root.to_xml.to_s` to render your string, see the examples on github, it's really straightforward.

Comment: I was a bit hesitant to make a class for each tag in the XML that I needed to render but the code ended up looking really great. Thanks